# Edit the labels of tables in wave analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics

I wanted to edit the labels of tables in wave analytics .I tried to edit the dataset by adding label but again it needs an xmd 2 version. can anyone suggest me a way to do it.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi user43076, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you need assistance learning the Salesforce technical environment, I recommend you look at the many workbooks available from [Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs) and also begin the learning path at [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/), particularly the Wave Analytics Modules.